# Image upload and data save conflicting in CakePHP3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to upload image in my cakephp 3.x application. When not uploading image, other data was saving fine but since the file upload integration, image uploading feature is working fine but other data isn't getting saved. Below is the sample code. Please see as I think there might be some minor issue only which I am missing to locate. Here is the code for add action in controller:

```
    $team_member = $this->TeamMembers->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if (!empty($this->request->data['photo']['name'])) {
            $photo = $this->request->data['photo'];

            $ext = substr(strtolower(strrchr($photo['name'], '.')), 1); //get the extension
            $arr_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'); //set allowed extensions
            $setNewFileName = time() . "_" . rand(000000, 999999);

            //only process if the extension is valid
            if (in_array($ext, $arr_ext)) {
                //do the actual uploading of the file. First arg is the tmp name, second arg is 
                //where we are putting it
                move_uploaded_file($photo['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . '/uploads/' . $setNewFileName . '.' . $ext);
                //prepare the filename for database entry 
                $imageFileName = $setNewFileName . '.' . $ext;
            }
        }

        $team_member = $this->TeamMembers->patchEntity($team_member, $this->request->data);
        if (!empty($this->request->data['photo']['name'])) {
            $team_member->photo = $imageFileName;
        }
        if ($this->TeamMembers->save($team_member)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Saved Successfully.'));
            return $this->redirect([
                    'action' => 'index'
            ]);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Failed to save. Try Again.'));
    }
    $this->set('team_member', $team_member);
```

Here is the add.ctp file:

```
echo $this->Form->create($team_member, ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']);
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->input('photo', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('excerpt');
echo $this->Form->input('content');
echo $this->Form->button('Save', ['class' => 'btn']);
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Please note that earlier it was working fine when I didn't wrote any code for file upload. And, the CakePHP version is 3.x

TIA

Answer (score -2):

I just got an answer. I don't know why is it working because logically this is incorrect but it is working fine now. 
I just replaced this line of code in add.ctp file

```
echo $this->Form->create($team_member, ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']);
```

to

```
echo $this->Form->create($team_member);
```

Anyways, it is working fine now. But still if you can clarify why is the case because every form having file upload should have enctype as multipart/form-data.

Comment: Normally it should be `$this->Form->create($team_member, ['type' => 'file']);`. I kinda doubt that it works without the proper encoding type set in the generated form. **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#changing-the-http-method-for-a-form**

Comment: I know enctype is must to define here but still if I add enctype or define ['type' => 'file'] it doesn't works. I have read this helper link and referred books many times but it's still not working that way. But, anyways, with this wrong code, it is working now. If you know why it happens, do let me know.